# C++, multiset, Time complexity

Tags: c++, time-complexity, multiset

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin>>n;
    char st[n];
    getchar();
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
        st[i]=getchar();
    std::multiset<char> s;
    int pos1=0,pos2=n-1;
    for (char c:st) s.insert(c);
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        if (s.count(st[i])==1) {
            pos1=i;
            break;
        } else s.erase(s.find(st[i]));
    }
    for (int i=n-1; i>=0; --i) {
        if (s.count(st[i])==1) {
            pos2=i;
            break;
        } else s.erase(s.find(st[i]));
    }
    std::cout<<pos2-pos1+1;
}
```

I have just summit this code to CodeForces system, and it fail the TL (2s), i dont know why, because n constrain is 10^5. And my code work with O(nlogn). Can u guys help me? Thanks <3<3. Link of problem here : http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/701/C

Comment: `char st[n];` is not allowed in C++ (unless `n` is a *compile-time constant*, which is not the case in your code).

Comment: oh, it work in the first 10 cases, and i even change array constant length, still not pass test 11 :(, i think it's not problem here

Comment: I understood that, but it means that their compiler is not conformant. Besides, it would be nice to explain what your code does, instead of referring to a problem description and letting us figure it out.

Comment: Because i just want u to help me analysis time-complexity, my code fail time-limit constrain. My english is not good, so it's hard for me to explain things :((

Comment: You can check out my code with constant array length here: http://codeforces.com/contest/701/submission/23616334, it work the same with above code !

Comment: I verified that your code is O(nlogn) but probably it is still not optimal.

Comment: Maybe it's not optimal solution, but why O(nlogn) algorithm fail TL test with boundary 10^5. That's my question :D. But thank you so much for trying to help me. Best wish for you mate !

Comment: There are faster ways to read the data.  You should stick with iostreams or stdio but don't mix both, it can be costly to keep different i/o buffers in sync.  Think about reading all the characters at once, not one at a time.  Your algorithm might be great but it won't matter if you take way to long to read the data.  If you choose streams then look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, your algorithm is `O(nlogn)` but this is not a garantee to not exceed a time limit. Remember that the multiplication constant for a big-O complexity may be too big to keep it under a certain time limit.

You are using a `multiset` only for keeping a count for each type of Pokemon. You lose much time to erase from that multiset and count again from it. You can do much faster than the `multiset`:

1. By using a `map` to keep the count for each type and to update it
2. Better yet, since pokemon types are encoded in single chars, you can use an array of `256` elements to keep track of the count. This way you can avoid the "log(n)" complexity of `multiset` (and `map`). Here's a refactored version of your code that should run much faster, and moreover it runs in  `O(n)`.

```cpp
int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<char> st(n);
    std::array<int, 256> count; // we could also use a map if we had a bigger set of types...

    // the way you read the input can also be speeded-up,
    // but I want to focus on speeding up the algorithm
    getchar();
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        st[i]=getchar(); ++count[st[i]];
    }

    int pos1=0,pos2=n-1;
    for (int i=0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (count[st[i]] == 1) {
            pos1 = i;
            break;
        } else --count[st[i]];
    }
    for (int i=n-1; i>=0; --i) {
        if (s.count(st[i])==1) {
            pos2=i;
            break;
        } else --count[st[i]];
    }
    std::cout<<pos2-pos1+1;
}
```